# I need the hospital name in my array to be shown in the dropdown with a truncated hospital name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my code:https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-butterfly-uqbf94?file=/src/App.js:0-1793

```js
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const hospitalList = {
  docs: [
    {
      _id: "1",
      hospCode: "1090123413",
      hospName: "AHS Southcrest Hospital, LLC dba Hillcrest Hospital South"
    },
    {
      _id: "2",
      hospCode: "2589230310",
      hospName: "Ascension Macomb-Oakland Hospital, Madison Heights Campus"
    },

    {
      _id: "3",
      hospCode: "300156700",
      hospName: "Atrium Health Wake Forest Baptist Health Wilkes Medical Center"
    },
    {
      _id: "4",
      hospCode: "40969123862",
      hospName: "CHI Health Creighton University Medical Center - Bergan Mercy"
    }
  ]
};
export default function App() {
  const [selectedHospital, setSelectedHospital] = useState();

  return (
    <div id="hospital-selector" className="mr-2 flex-1 ">
      <Autocomplete
        sx={{ maxLine: 1 }}
        disableListWrap
        loading={hospitalList.docs.length <= 0}
        options={hospitalList.docs}
        onChange={(option, value) => {
          if (
            value &&
            Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, "hospCode")
          ) {
            setSelectedHospital(value);
          }
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            required
            placeholder="Select hospital"
            variant="outlined"
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps
            }}
          />
        )}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.hospCode}: ${option.hospName}`}
        limitTags={15}
        getLimitTagsText={(more) => {
          console.log("More:" + more);
          return `+${more}`;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Current result:
In the search bar each one of the hospital names can take one line or two lines if the text is too long, but what I need the result to be like is every hospital name can only take one line. If the text is too long, I want to truncate the hospital name with a 15 character limit and then show ... (Example: Ascension Macomb-Oakland Hospital, Madison Heights...)

Comment: Have you tried changing the getOptionLabel prop to display 3 dots if `option.hospName.length > 15`?

Comment: @Ezrab_ I try but result it's not what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can style the options with CSS:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. But it did not work.